# Convert MYSQL time from HH:MM:SS to HH:MM during PHP Select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a PHP Select statement to pull data from MySQL. The eventTime field is stored as TIME in the schema as HH:MM:SS but I only want HH:MM. I have tried using TIME_FORMAT(eventTime, '%H:%i') in the select statement but it does not work. Any ideas? I have even tried to convert the variable in PHP but I am stumped. Please help me identify what I'm missing.

```
$query="SELECT id,eventDate,eventTime, eventName FROM specialevents ORDER BY eventDate,eventTime ASC";

$result=$mysqliConnection->query($query,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

while($row =$result->fetch_object())
  {


     $id=$row->id;
     $eventDate=$row->eventDate;
     $eventTime=$row->eventTime;
     $eventName=$row->eventName;
     $reportTime=$row->reportTime;

 echo '<tr>’; 
 echo '<td class="tdId"><input type="text" class="tbId" value="' . $id . '"/></td>’; 
 echo '<td class="tdEventDate"><input type="text" class="tbEventDate" value="' . $eventDate . '"/></td>’; 
 echo '<td class="tdEventTime"><input type="text" class="tbEventTime" value="' . $eventTime . '"/></td>’; 
 echo '<td class="tdEventName"><input type="text" class="tbEventName" value=" ' . $eventTime . '"/></td>’; 
 echo '<td class="tdReportTime"><input type="text" class="tbReportTime" value=" ' . $reportTime . '"/></td>';   

}
```

Comment: `TIME hh:mm:ss`? The field literally contains the word `TIME`? If so, then it's not a time-type field, and it's probably text/varchar, which means you can NOT use the mysql date/time functions on its contents directly.

Comment: yes in the database structure the eventTime field is stored as TIME not datetime or timestamp. The format is HH:MM:SS. I just want to cull the SS.

Comment: ah. so it's a literal `time` type? or `datetime`? Either way, `SELECT TIME(datetimefield)` or `SELECT TIME(timefield)` would return only the time component, in `hh:mm:ss` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing date and time separately if they refer to the same entity. However, you can use MySQL's [`TIME_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function to format your time:

> ```
> TIME_FORMAT(date,format)
> ```
>
> Formats the date value according to the format string.

```
$query="SELECT id, eventDate, TIME_FORMAT(eventTime, '%H:%i') AS eventTime, eventName 
FROM specialevents 
ORDER BY eventDate, eventTime ASC";
```

You can use the specifiers from [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format as you wish.

Also, the `ASC` sort order is default and can be omitted from your query.

Comment: The way the data is stored is out of my control but I did indeed try the DATE_FORMAT and TIME_FORMAT in my php SELECT statement but the I'm unable to get it to work. It seems very straight forward but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Should be TIME_FORMAT(eventTime, '%H:%i') correct?

Comment: @HbrownMedic You need to make sure you're aliasing it (`.. AS eventTime`).

Comment: Hmm can you give me a a little better example as to how to alias it with the TIME_FORMAT? I think you are on to something. Thanks

Comment: @HbrownMedic It's in my answer.

Comment: Kermit you are the man...Thank you. I was applying the TIME_FORMAT without the alias and it just would not work. With the Alias it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP (not sure on MySQL) you can do the following:

`$formatted_date = date('H:i:s', strtotime($mysql_timedate));`

Comment: I did try that. Two problems that I encountered. The first is that the date in mySQL is stored at time. Not timestamp or date time. Even when I apply that format is doesn't remove the seconds from the time. It seems to have no effect. Thank you though.

Comment: Is the mysql schema actually TIME or VARCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have column of type time 
**The Php approach as follows :**

```
$new_time = date('H:i', strtotime($mysql_timedate)); // mysql_timedate is the row containg time form the db and outout is hour:mins
```

**Mysql approach :**

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column name here, '%H:%i') FROM table name"; // output hour:mins
```